# Behaviour of String.split() when input is empty

Tags: java, string, split

As the title explains the query

Can somebody please explain the behavior of following two outputs.

```
"".split(",").length
```

gives output

```
1
```

where as

```
",".split(",").length
```

gives output

```
0
```

Comment: You should have looked up and read the javadoc before you asked this question.

Comment: How does this get 5 upvotes? No effort was done.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis How did the answer get +15? ;-)

Comment: @DuncanJones **SO** is generous sometimes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the first case, the original string is returned, because the separator is not found.

From the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

Comment: Who would have guessed?  The javadoc has the answer!

Comment: @StephenC To be slightly fair, the comment is only mentioned in the [`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) variant.

Comment: @DuncanJones - But I bet that the `split(String regex)` version says "see the other variant for details"!

Comment: `Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.` is part of the `String#split(String)` method. Not being fair. And Stephen is correct ^. `This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method... `

Comment: @DuncanJones - True, though that is linked indirectly through the single-argument method's comment: "This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method ."

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer Ah, true. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

Trailing empty strings are discarded.

Try:

```
"Foo,".split(",").length // should be 1
",foo".split(",").length // should be 1
```