# Peculiar behavior of split() of string class

Tags: java, string

To my understanding following program should print `0,0` as an output.

However, when I run this program I am getting `1,0` as an output.

```
public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("".split(";").length); //1
        System.out.println(";".split(";").length);//0
    }
}
```

Please help me understand what is going on here ?

Comment: Here is the same question tagged with Scala: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array Rok Kralj's answer addresses this particular inconsistency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array#37796531

Comment: @nullpointer--Please check the lang type, its for scala!!!! Do you think both scala and java are same ???

Comment: @LoneWolf Does it make a difference? Do you have any problems applying this to Java?

Comment: @defaultlocale-- Yes it does because they both are different languages and with different language specs...please read the following answers

Comment: @LoneWolf This is not a language issue, I'm afraid. Java and Scala share an SDK (String class in particular). And there is an answer that deals specifically with Java, please read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964484/why-does-split-on-an-empty-string-return-a-non-empty-array#37796531 Do we really need to copy it here?

Comment: @defaultlocale-- Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: More for that language sake https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655415/string-array-length-is-showing-1-even-the-array-is-empty-after-call-split-by-com?noredirect=1&lq=1,  ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216524/behaviour-of-string-split-when-input-is-empty ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157058/string-split-behaviour-on-empty-string-and-on-single-delimiter-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

relavant code

```
        // If no match was found, return this
        if (off == 0)
            return new String[]{this};

        // Add remaining segment
        if (!limited || list.size() < limit)
            list.add(substring(off, value.length));
```

Comment: This is actually the answer to the question.

Comment: I would drop in the lines above `if( off == 0)` for more context.

Answer (score 5):

In the first case, because there is simply no match, the string will be returned as per this part of the Javadoc:

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

As for your second case, in the event that a split does occur, the trailing empty strings will be removed:

> If *n* is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

(emphasis mine)

Source: [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the document here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

"If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string"

Since the input doesn't contain the regex i.e. ";" it returns the entire string.

Answer (score 3):

You found a cool edge case:
If a string does not contain the char you split it by an array containing only that string is returned

If the separating char is in the string then you get an array containing all split, except the empty strings.

So in the second case the result should be an array with two empty string, but the split function removes them. In the first case, since split did not actually split anything, and it does not remove anything.

Comment: `";;;;".length` gives 0, and `";;;1;".length` gives 3. The second case is a very crazy and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks user....:) for justification